# Compare elements in two lists

Tags: java, algorithm, list, groovy, compare

I have two lists containing integers, like this:

```
def first = [10, 12, 3, 6, 9, 8, 33]
def second = [8, 9, 5, 6]
```

Number of elements in each list can be completely arbitrary. Also I have a threshold, which is also a number:

```
def threshold = 3
```

I have to pairwise check compare all elements in both arrays and check if their difference is <= threshold. As a results I have to output all that elements.

So, in my case it is:
`10, 12, 3, 6, 9, 8` from first list and `8, 9, 5, 6` from second. Because

```
abs(10-8) <= 3
abs(12-9) <= 3
abs(3-5) <= 3
abs(6-6) <= 3
```

And here due to the fact that first list contains more elements then the second, I have to compare first list elements with last element from second list.

```
abs(9-6) <= 3
abs(8-6) <= 3
abs(33-6) >= 3, stop here!
```

Groovy and Java answers are suitable.

P.S Is it an algorithmic problem and some algorithm already exist for such purposes?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question here is. It seems like a very simplistic problem which can be solved with a straight forward for loop in O(n). What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a java way to get it done.  Since you `abs()` the subtraction it doesn't matter which comes first.  So lets take advantage of that and figure out which is longer.  Once we know that, we know which one to force to repeat it's last element.

```
if (first.length() > second.length()) {
    longer = first;
    shorter = second;
} else {
    longer = second;
    shorter = first;
}

last = shorter.length() - 1;

for(int i = 0; i < longer.length(); i++) {
    s = shorter.get(Math.min(last, i));
    l = longer.get(i);
    if (abs(l-s) > threshold) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the following implementation i have used set data structure to prevent elements duplication in the result , if you want to display duplicate elements you can use arraylist instead of set

```
import java.util.*;
   public class CompareElements{



      public static void main(String[ ] arg){


        int [] firstList = {10, 12, 3, 6, 9, 8, 33};
        int [] secondList = {8, 9, 5, 6};

        int firstListLength = firstList.length;
        int secondListLength = secondList.length;
        // i have used set data structure to prevent duplication of elements in the result
        Set<Integer>result=new HashSet<Integer>();

        // iterate over the two list and get the absolute value for each two corresponding elements
        // and check if the difference is <= 3 , the two elements are added to the result 
        for(int i=0;i<Math.min(firstList.length, secondList.length);i++) {
            if(Math.abs(firstList[i]-secondList[i]) <= 3)
            {
                result.add(firstList[i]);
                result.add(secondList[i]);
            }
        }

        // here we are trying to handle the case when the lists have different lengths
        // and the second list length is greater 
        if(firstListLength < secondListLength)
        {
            for(int i =firstListLength-1;i<secondListLength;i++)
            {
                if(Math.abs(firstList[firstListLength-1]-secondList[i]) <= 3)
                {
                    result.add(firstList[firstListLength-1]);
                    result.add(secondList[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        // here we are trying to handle the case when the lists have different lengths
        // and the first list length is greater 
        else if (firstListLength > secondListLength)
        {
            for(int i =secondListLength-1;i<firstListLength;i++)
            {
                if(Math.abs(firstList[i]-secondList[secondListLength-1]) <= 3)
                {
                    result.add(firstList[i]);
                    result.add(secondList[secondListLength-1]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());





       }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the horrible final repeated element restriction, in groovy this is:

```
[first,second].transpose()
              .every { Math.abs(it[0]-it[1]) < threshold }
```

#### Edit

Given this function to pad lists to being a certain width (defaulting to the max length of the lists):

```
def paddedPairs(List lists, Integer width=lists*.size().max()) {
    (0..<width).collect { p -> lists.collect { it[ p >= it.size() ? -1 : p] } }
}
```

You can do:

```
paddedPairs([first, second]).every { Math.abs(it[0]-it[1]) < threshold }
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not compare elements when lists have different size. So, it  is not working correctly.

Comment: @Bob Added a function to pad the lists to the same length :-)